# Not able to scroll within a page using AngularJS in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a simple html code where I have a left menu. I want to scroll content on click of menu within the same page. Also I don't want to scroll menu.
The problem is, I am using AngularJS so compiler is confused between routing and segment logic.
Here is my menu:

```
<div class="container">
    <div style="float: left;width:150px;">
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#clinical">overview</a></li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Clinical features</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Diagnosis</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Testing laboratories</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Result interpretation</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-10" id="clinical">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">Result interpretation</div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <p style="text-align: right;">Back To Top</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <p>Hey this is just to test.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the code that scrolls the page?

Comment: After updating your question, I've noticed lots of code being hidden at first (due to missing indentation). Are you using *Bootstrap* for this?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a problem specific to AngularJS or anything else. It's just a tiny CSS problem:

You're aligning your menu using `float: left`, which will cause it to appear on the left border but it won't follow you down when scrolling (as you've noticed).

The solution is pretty simple, just attach your menu in a different way. There are many different ways to do this, also depending on whether you're using any JavaScript library (like Bootstrap), but the most simple approach would be pinning the menu using CSS:

```
.menubar {
    /* A fixed alignment will ignore scroll bar positions */
    position: fixed;

    /* Stretch the bar by forcing offsets and a width */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 150px;
}
```

Last but not least you'll have to move your content so it's not hidden by the menu bar (which would otherwise overlap):

```
.content {
    padding-left: 150px; /* of course this could use positioning as well */
}
```

[You can try the whole thing in this jsFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/Smaxx/cva2hLky/)

From your question it's not clear whether you're also looking for soft scrolling, but for that you'll most likely want some additional JavaScript library - or you could just use some library that provides everything for you (including menu bar CSS etc.), like [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) or [UI Kit](https://getuikit.com/).